# Optimizing Execution Time with PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm processing roughly not less than 25,000 records. However, it somehow exceed the maximum execution time. I am using Codeigniter 3.0.

The Records was the text data from a PDF that was processed by the library I made. It seemed to be not exceeding the execution time if I only show it, but when things starts to be complicated, like processing it to the database(MySQL), it exceeds the 300sec(I reconfigured this) execution time.

To illustrate

```
  function process() {

        $data = processThePDF(); //outputs the records / 25,000 records

        if ($data) {
                    foreach ($data as $dt) {

                        $info = $this->just_another_model->view($dt['id']); //get the old record

                        if ($info) {
                            //update
                            $this->just_another_model->update([$params]);
                            //Log Update
                            $this->just_another_model->log([$params]);
                        } else {
                            //Register
                            $this->just_another_model->update([$params]);
                            //Log Register
                            $this->just_another_model->log([$params]);
                        }
                    }
                }
}
```

So my questions are:
1. Is there a better way to optimize this?
2. Is convenient to write a json file or a text file before processing it?

Comment: 25,000 records isn't really that much data; the fact that it's taking _five minutes_ is strange and alarming. If there's nothing obviously wrong with the logic/implementation, though, this seems like something that should be run on cron or from a queue, depending on how processing is done, as opposed to being triggered directly by an HTTP request.

Comment: Nothing obviously wrong with the code. Just a couple of questions... Where is `$params` coming from and what are the model functions doing? It seems that the extra time comes from there

Answer (score 0):

Store your data in an array and update/insert it by batch.

```
function process() {

$data = processThePDF(); //outputs the records / 25,000 records
$update_data = array();
$update_data_2 = array();

if ($data) {
    foreach ($data as $dt) {

        $info = $this->just_another_model->view($dt['id']); //get the old record

        if ($info) {        
            $update_data[] = array($params);
        } else {
            $update_data_2[] = array($params);
        }
    }

    if(count(update_data) > 0) 
        $this->just_another_model->update_batch($update_data);
    if(count(update_data_2) > 0)
        $this->just_another_model_2->update_batch($update_data_2);
}
```

Furthermore, you can get your old records by batch before the loop and format it into array that so you can access it by id: `$old_records[$dt['id']]`

Comment: This is interesting.